# objective c sqlite no select works

Tags: objective-c

I can't make a Select on a table in a sqlite database.

I have the following code to copy the .sqlite-file to the user's directory:

```
    // copy the database to the user's directory
- (void)checkAndCreateDB {
    // Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
    BOOL success;

    // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
    // of the database and to copy it over if required
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
    if(success) return;

    // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

    // Get the path to the database in the application package
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:databaseName ofType:nil];
    // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
    [fileManager release];
}
```

And the select here:

```
sqlite3 *database;

categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sqlStatement = "select * from category";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    NSLog(@"get");
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"test");
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString *cId = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                NSString *cName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

                Category *category = [[Category alloc] initWithId:cId name:cName];
                [categories addObject:category];
                [categories release];
            } 

    }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
```

the log shows only: "get". "test" isn't there.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Add else block with something like NSLog(@”Error: %s”, sqlite3_errmsg(database)); to all your if statement, it will show errors. It will simplify understanding whats wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your database copy code isn't working as you are passing `nil` to the `ofType` parameter of `[NSBundle pathForResource]`.  Try passing the correct file extension and add code to detect the success or failure of the copy operation (and make your `checkAndCreateDB` method return `BOOL`) and take it from there.

Your database select code looks OK to me, so I'm guess you have an empty database as explained in @Micheal's answer.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3_open will create a new (empty) database if the one specified doesn't exist. To make sure that this isn't what's happening, try using sqlite3_open_v2 instead and use SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE as the flags argument. That way you'll get an error if you attempt to open a database that doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi Michael. Thank you for the answer. It does still not work.

if(sqlite3_open_v2([databasePath UTF8String], &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

is the new code I have. So you think the copy-code does not work?

Answer (score -1):

There is an example project for using SQLite here you can refer to: https://github.com/AaronBratcher/ABSQLite

It has classes for accessing SQLite in a more traditional database way that I feel makes things easier.